# Get values from web service reference C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, soap

I'm having a problem with calling a method in a web reference:

[image]

This is my web service:

[image]

What is the correct way to do this?

Thank you.. :)

Comment: Paste your code here. so people can try it

Comment: Take a look at the definition of the HelloWorld method on the reference client

Comment: As per your screenshot, the method signature expects an instance of HelloWorldRequest as parameter and returns an instance of HelloWorldResponse. It does not return a string.

Comment: AuthenticationService.HelloWorldRequest request = new AuthenticationService.HelloWorldRequest(); ;
            AuthenticationService.AuthenticationSoap CallWebService = new AuthenticationService.AuthenticationSoapClient();
            AuthenticationService.HelloWorldResponse respond = CallWebService.HelloWorld(request);
            string x =respond.Body.HelloWorldResult;

Thank you.. :)